# Why do my open applications keep tiling across my desktop?

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I'm working on a Windows 10 machine using my Mac trackpad. Multiple times a day when I'm moving my mouse cursor, suddenly my active window disappears and I see all my open windows tiled in a grid. Similar to alt-tab but in a grid. Or when you Win+LEFT and it shows you a grid of applications to select for the right side of the screen.

Clearly it's some handy feature to let me see and select/organise my open applications, but I've no idea what it's called or what gesture I'm unwittingly making!
Maybe I can avoid it, maybe I can disable it as it's pretty distracting!

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful here.

Comment: Is it perhaps the Win+Tab view?

Comment: You are likely activating a trackpad gesture.  You could try uninstalling any software assosiated with the trackpad.  I have no idea if that software exists, typically trackpad gesture questions, are limited to OEM hardware not Macs running Windows

Comment: @NiallJonesI'll try to next time - have to obscure some work stuff.